# How to boot DE1-SoC from non-volatile storage on the board itself?

Tags: memory, hardware, fpga, non-volatile

I have a DE1-SoC Board and would like to experiment with it.
(Board description: 
http://www.terasic.com.tw/cgi-bin/page/archive.pl?Language=English&CategoryNo=205&No=836&PartNo=1)

My wish is to incorporate non-volatile storage.

As for a start, implementing the following exercise would make me happy:

```
When the board is turned on, the integer stored in memory should appear in 
readable format on HEX LEDS.
```

So far I have implemented the "ability" to change the value of HEX LEDS using extra buttons connected to board. However, if the board is turned off, the whole "ability" is gone. I then need to reconnect the board to my PC and re-download the binary code to FPGA. In addition to that, the value stored in LEDS is also reset to default. I would like to avoid having reconnect my FPGA to computer.

**How to start working on this?**

Looking at board documentation for memory:

```
64MB (32Mx16) SDRAM on FPGA
1GB (2x256Mx16) DDR3 SDRAM on HPS
Micro SD Card Socket on HPS
```

**Does it mean that DE1-SoC has no non-volatile storage incorporated? If it does, how to access it?**

I also have all pin assignments of the board in a single file "de1soc_pin_assignments.qsf"

**Can I connect external SD card to "Micro SD Card Socket" and use it as a flash? Is it possible to "boot" the binary code from SD card to FPGA (as well as the integer number to LEDS)? If yes, which pin should I use for that?**

Thanks a lot for your help in advance

Comment: Could someone explain why this post got down-voted, so that I wouldn't post similar things in the future?

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with your question hence I've +1'ed it. It does happen sometimes on here for various reasons that baffle. I think it's people are different and see things different. Also down-vote questions is free for the voter in contrast to down-vote answers. Don't let it get to you.

Comment: Thanks :-) . Similar post got down-voted because "general questions about hardware should be posted on SuperUser instead". I would remove this question as well now, but it already has an answer. In any case, as you said, I probably should not worry too much, it's just one question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DE1-SOC includes an EPCS128 configuration flash, which can be used to store the bitstream for your design. See page 105 of the [DE1-SOC user manual](https://www.terasic.com.tw/cgi-bin/page/archive_download.pl?Language=English&No=930&FID=c48fce92d985024f399bac7860668452) ("Programming the EPCS Device") for details on how to convert a bitstream to the appropriate format and store it on the flash chip. Once you've done so, the FPGA will "boot" into that bitstream when powered on, without needing to be plugged into a computer.

The configuration flash cannot easily be used to store other data, such as the state of your LEDs. It might be possible to store this data on an SD card, but doing so will not be an easy task, as SD cards require a complex initialization process before they can be accessed.